# Php syntax error, unexpected $end in

Tags: php

Im getting this error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home2/user1221/public_html/Registration.php on line 13"

sorry im noob and i dont know whats problame. should i post here my html code too ?

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/connection.php';

if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) {
    $error = array(); 
    if (empty($_POST['FirstName'])) { 
        $error[] = 'Please Enter a name ';
    } else {
        $nameF = $_POST['FirstName'];
    }

?>
```

Comment: You forget to close your first `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing brace for the `if` isset

Add like this

```
    } else {
        $nameF = $_POST['FirstName'];
    }
} //<--- Add Here
```

Answer (score 0):

missing the parenthesis for the first if condition ,so please } after this line

```
 $nameF = $_POST['FirstName'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

unexpected $end error mostly occurs when any of the curly braces of if condition is not closed properly. So you should check it always before taking your time to post the question on stackoverflow. That's a good practice to detect the error on own basis.